# Integration by Parts of t ln(2t) with limits of e/2 and 1/2

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral as the following:

$$\int_{1/2}^{e/2} t ln(2t) dt$$

I'm having troubles writing down my progress on using MathJax, skipping a few scenes, this is where I'm stuck at $$ =[\frac{e^3}{16}(ln2) - \frac{1}{16} (ln2)] - [ \frac{e^2}{16} - \frac{1}{16}] $$

the answer is  $$ =\frac{1}{16}(e^2+1)$$ but i care less about the answer, i'm more curious about the factorization taken place to get to just that.
 
 Edit: I think i have solved the problem thanks to user,user284331.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^{e/2}t\ln(2t)dt&=\dfrac{1}{2}t^{2}\ln(2t)\bigg|_{t=1/2}^{t=e/2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^{e/2}t^{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2t}\cdot 2dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{e^{2}}{4}\right)-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^{e/2}tdt\\
&=\dfrac{e^{2}}{8}-\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{e^{4}}{4}-\dfrac{1}{4}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: oh.OHHHHHHHHH. thanks a bunch for the lead!